# Change source of image field with javascript in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a listbox in an Adobe Acrobat form. When I change the value of the listbox, the source of the image field has to be changed with a javascript script:

[image]

As a first step, I tried to change the src in javascript, so not yet with the listbox:

```
var logo = this.getField("companylogo"); // button field
logo.buttonImportIcon("C:\Users\VincentJanssens\Downloads\Blauw.png")
```

But even this code isn't working.
Thank you for getting me started!

Comment: Do you want the list box to just swap the current image with a new one from a fixed set of images or did you want the user to upload a new image? Also, will this script only be used in Acrobat Standard or Pro and not in Reader or do you need to support Reader too?

Comment: I just want to swap the current image with a new one from a fixed set of images. The script only has to work with Acrobat Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be very simple if you set the fields up to allow for that. The first step is to create buttons for each of the images you want to be available. Name these buttons such that the Export Value of the item in the Dropdown matches exactly. Set these buttons to Hidden and Read Only in the General tab.
[image]

Then add a button where you want the various images to appear on your form. Set this field to read-only too. Now, set up the Dropdown to Commit the selected value immediately and add the following JavaScript to the Format script of the dropdown. Replace the string 'displayImage' with the name of the button field you placed on your form.

```
 this.getField("displayImage").buttonSetIcon(this.getField(event.target.value).buttonGetIcon())
```

[image]

Now each time the list item changes, the script will run and use the Export Value of the field to get the button icon from the button with the same name as the export value.

I've posted a working example file [here](https://practicalpdf.com/techniques/pdf/ChangeGraphicBasedOnFieldValue.pdf).

Comment: This worked! Do you have a solution for adding in bulk? I have 80 images so it's a bit of work...

Comment: It's possible if the filenames of the images are such that you can use a loop to create a string of the name. If not, it's going to be very manual.

Comment: I can change the filenames the way I want...so I guess the string will work? Is it possible to add this loop in the example file please? I'm not so familiar with string loops...

Comment: Ok - Post importing images in bulk as a new question and I can provide some code. Also, please mark my answer to this one as correct if you think it is.

Comment: Please see post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332970/importing-images-in-bulk-in-acrobat